# Data-packets, sent to a router, are treated differently based on their origin: clarification needed

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ping, packet-tracer

On a Cisco Packet Tracer sample [e2-232](http://lifebeam.net/cisco/files/e2-232.pka), there is something I don't understand, even after following the step-by-step instructions on the sample project.The logical topology is shown in the following screen-shot.

[image]

Result of pings are shown below:

- on **PC2** : ping *172.16.1.1* interface of **R2**: <kbd>OK</kbd>
- on **PC2** : ping *172.16.2.2* interface of **R2**: <kbd>OK</kbd>
- on **PC2** : ping *192.168.1.2* interface of **R2**: <kbd>OK</kbd>
- on **R1** : ping *172.16.1.1* interface of **R2**: <kbd>NOT GOOD</kbd>
- on **R1** : ping *172.16.2.2* interface of **R2**: <kbd>OK</kbd>
- on **R1** : ping *192.168.1.2* interface of **R2**: <kbd>NOT GOOD</kbd>

Now, my question is why `ping`results on **R1**, which is a router, are different from those on **PC2**, which is a desktop computer. Considering the fact that both **R1** and **PC2** are directly connected to **R2**, why are the data-packets, sent to **R2**, treated differently based on their origin?

---

Running-Configurations of **R1** are as follows:

```
Router#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 713 bytes
!
version 12.3
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 1
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.3.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 172.16.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 no login
!
!
!
end
```

Also, **R2** running-configurations are:

```
Router#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 724 bytes
!
version 12.3
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 1
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 172.16.2.2 255.255.255.0
 clock rate 64000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 no login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: You need to include the router configurations in you question. We cannot simply guess where you went wrong (that is off-topic here).

Comment: @RonMaupin Right, I included.

Comment: No. Do a `show running-configuration` on each router, and paste the results into your question. We need the configurations.

Comment: @RonMaupin I included results of `Router#show running-config` command, but they are a bit lengthy.

Comment: They are not at all lengthy compared to a lot of what we get here. I think you are allowed 30,000 characters in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routers have no routes to non-connected networks. Routers get routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through dynamic routing protocols

You need to use one or both of the last two methods for a router to learn about networks not directly connected to it.

The PC can ping a host, e.g. its router, on the same LAN, and it will have the router as its gateway, so it can reach any networks about which its router knows (the router's directly connected routes). A different router doesn't know about the network where the PC is attached, so the router has no way to know to send that traffic to the router for that network.

Comment: So, If I define a `Gateway of last resort` for R1, would the ping results on R1 be just like those on PC2?

Comment: No. Routers are the gateways, they do not use gateways if they are routing. You either need to define static routes, which do not scale, or you need to configure your routers with a common routing protocol.

Comment: Right, also as a reference, on [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/16448-default.html) it is mentioned that the `ip default-gateway` command ... should only be used when ip routing is disabled on the Cisco router. Thanks.

Comment: The default-gateway command is used for network devices as hosts. Routers that are routing use routes, not gateways because they are the gateways. Hosts use gateways. What you need to do is use the `ip route` command, and put in routes for non-attached networks pointing to the next router. That is static routing, which doesn't scale. To do it correctly, you configure a common routing protocol on all your routers.

Comment: It's much more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

It's because R1 doesn't know how to reach those other interfaces (it doesn't have routes for those networks).  You need routes on R1 pointing to R2 for the other two subnets.  R1 of course knows how to reach 172.16.2.2 because it has an interface on that network.

Comment: But how are data-packets, coming from PC2, routed without any problem?

Comment: But how does PC2 know how to reach those interfaces?

Comment: Because R2 is the default gateway for PC2, and R2 is attached to all of those networks.  PC2 only knows how to get to R2 as the default gateway, but R2 can reach all of those networks.

Comment: When data-packets or data-frames are received by R2, does it make any difference whether they are from R1 or PC2? why is R2 capable of routing packets originally from PC2, but it cannot route packets from R1? I still don't get it.

Comment: R2 is not the issue.  R2 treats packets the same.  The problem is that R1 does not know how to get to those networks (missing routes) so the packets never leave R1 in the first place.  PC2 knows how to get there via its default gateway.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot. I wish I could accept two answers.